# Unable to install adobe-flashplugin

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, flash, adobe

i tried to install adobe-flashplugin ubuntu 18.04 but i got the following message;

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
adobe-flashplugin : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
Recommends: adobe-flash-properties-gtk (= 1:20200811.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed

Please, can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you tried to install the `adobe-flashplugin` package for focal on a bionic install.

Do it the right way instead: Enable [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) and then install the bionic version of `adobe-flashplugin` from there.

More reading about Flash:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html